# Loop through Struct to check a value

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct

PHP programer here struggling with Swift.
How do I create a Struct (Mutidimentional array in PHP) and walk through the elements to check a value?

Here is the code I am trying but it fails:

```
        struct Alert: Codable {
            let begin: Double
            let end: Double
            let color: String
            let message: String
        }

        var alertStack = [ Int: Alert ]()
        
        alertStack[60] = Alert(begin: 60.0,
                               end: 55.0,
                               color: "green",
                               message: "60 Seconds" )
        alertStack[30] = Alert(begin: 30.0,
                               end: 25.0,
                               color: "yellow",
                               message: "30 Seconds!")
        
        var alrtColor = "default" // Set default
        var alrtText = "" // Set default
       
        
        for alrt in alertStack {
            if alrt.begin <= secondsLeft {
                alrtColor = alrt.color // <-- Error
                alrtText = alrt.message
            }
        }
```

Error is "Value of tuple type 'Dictionary<Int, Alert>.Element' (aka '(key: Int, value: Alert)') has no member 'begin'"
For a PHP guy this error message is confusing.  I tried a few other things but can't seem to get the result I am looking for.  I am hoping there is a simple fix or example that would work.

Comment: The error says that `alrt` is `(key: Int, value: Alert)` so you get the properties from the `value`: -> `alrt.value.begin`

Comment: The bit you may be missing in understanding the above solution from @vadian, is that with Swift when you iterate through a swift dictionary it returns the <key: value> pair as the element, not just the value.

Comment: You can learn about dictionaries in Swift [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate each key value pair in a dictionary like so:

```
for (i, alrt) in alertStack
```

Where "i" would be your int value

But: it may be better to try to find a more Swifty way of expressing your problem (what are you trying to do?) rather than trying to translate from PHP.  For example, perhaps like:

```
let alerts: [Alert] = [
    (60, 55, "green", "60 Seconds"),
    (30, 25, "yellow", "30 Seconds!")
]
.map(Alert.init(begin:end:color:message:))

let color: String
let alertText: String

if let foundAlert = alerts.last(where: { $0.begin < secondsLeft }) {
    color = foundAlert.color
    alertText = foundAlert.message
}
else {
    color = "default"
    alertText = ""
}
```

(Maybe there is a reason but I don't know why you would want to have them in a dictionary keyed by their begin numbers)

If it helps I would imagine your problem may be expressed something like this:

```
struct Alert: Codable {
    let color: String
    let message: String

    static let defaultAlert = Alert(color: "default", message: "")

    static let thresholds: [ClosedRange<Double>: Alert] = [
        55...60: Alert(color: "green", message: "60 Seconds"),
        25...30: Alert(color: "yellow", message: "30 Seconds!")
    ]
}

func currentAlert(value: Double) -> Alert {
    // Return the alert where the range of seconds contains
    // the provided remaining seconds value
    guard let found = Alert.thresholds.first(where: {
        $0.key.contains(value)
    }) else {
        return .defaultAlert
    }

    return found.value
}


print(currentAlert(value: 57)) // 60 Seconds
print(currentAlert(value: 42)) // default
print(currentAlert(value: 26)) // 30 Seconds!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that's not a big deal. Everything you need to do is write **alrt.value.begin**, **alrt.value.color** and **alrt.value.message**. That's because of **alertStack** is `Dictionary<Int, Alert>` (or `[Int: Alert]`, it's the same) type. And **alrt** is element of Dictionary that always has **key** and **value** properties. In your case **key** is `Int`, **value** is `Alert`

```
for alrt in alertStack {
    if alrt.value.begin <= secondsLeft {
        alrtColor = alrt.value.color
        alrtText = alrt.value.message
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually was a simple solution to my original problem and I was tempted to accept it as best answer.  But ultimately the other answer went further to suggest a possibly better solution to my overall task.  Thank you for your answer.